# Animated gif preloaders generator

Tags: gif

How can I to create animated colorized gifs from templates in PHP? For example, when I go to preloaders.net, I choose some template and then can change it foreground color. How can I to correctly change colors in gif?

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary for to have ***GIF*** preloader graphics? If not, you could try a more contemporary approach. Also, much more configurable:

- [Loading spinner animation using CSS and WebKit](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2577-loading-spinner-animation-using-css-and-webkit) (37 Signals)
- [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/) *"An animated CSS activity indicator"* ← very slick

Comment: Yes, I want to do some server-side service. I think HSV model can helps me. Am I right? Can anybody give good article about it?

Comment: If you are thinking about the Hue-Saturation-Value (HSV) color model, the english [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is quite informative and should provide you with all needed info.

Comment: I mean any articles about changing colors using HSV.

Comment: I assume your question has been answerered, then. If not, please take your time to define our question more precisely.

Comment: I don't know why you think my question has been answered. But ok, I'll create new question about HSV.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CanvasLoader?

http://heartcode.robertpataki.com/canvasloader/

No need to worry about GIFs, it's using the HTML5 Canvas element

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I am not sure how my answer is any different to myhd's answer for example. CanvasLoader is an open source and free service, I have never made any money of it, so this isn't really self promotion. However if you think that my answer doesn't add value to this thread, feel free to remove it.